# Append penultimate line

Tags: java, android, file, append

I'm currently storing the read file in a `List<String>`, adding my `String` to the penultimate position of the list, and finally writing my list into the original file.

It works fine because my file is only 20ish lines, but I feel like it would be a really long process with a bigger file.

Hence my question is : Is there a `Append`-like method to simply choose the position where you want to append your line ?

Answer (score 0):

Just open a [java.io.FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) with append mode and just write your single String.

Use the following constructor of this class is:

`FileOutputStream(String name, boolean append)`

This is for appending to the end of the file.

You can use [java.io.RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) for editing anywhere inside a file.

EDIT:
Sample code to achieve the task using RandomAccessFile.

```
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class InsertPenultimateLine {

    private static String nl = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    private static void usingRAF() throws Exception {
        String fileName = "somefile.txt";
        String myLine = "blah-blah-blah";

        RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");

        List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
        long len = raf.length();
        long index = len-1;
        for(;index>0;index--) {
            raf.seek(index);
            byte b = raf.readByte();
            if(b == 10) {
                break;
            }
            bytes.add(0, b);
        }

        byte[] rawBytes = new byte[bytes.size()];
        for(int j=0;j<bytes.size();j++) {
            rawBytes[j] = bytes.get(j);
        }
        String str = new String(rawBytes);
        str = myLine + nl + str;

        raf.seek(index + 1);
        raf.write(str.getBytes());

        raf.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        usingRAF();
    }
}
```

Comment: This will only allow me to write at the end of the file, not to choose the position.

Comment: I am trying with RandomAccessFile but I have to read the whole File, search for the Integer position of penultimate line, then use `RandomAccessFile.Seek(int)` before writing. Not sure it would be better than my current solution...

Comment: @Arty if you are storing the entire file in the `List<String>` then that could be fine for small files. If the file size is big(say 500MB), then caching it in the list may not be a scalable way. Btw, you need not read the entire file to call the `seek` method. Use the `length` method to get the length of the whole file. If you have an approximate length for a single line, then you can use it to reach the previous line(s).

Comment: It seems that the `RandomAccessFile.WriteChars(String)` overwrites written bits. Exemple : If I write "test" in "abcdefghijklmno" at 'g' position I got "abcdeftestklmno", and I want "abcdeftestghijklmno"